# address.transfer no transaction on etherscan

Tags: solidity, transactions, etherscan, fallback-function

I tested fallback function in my smart contract, and noticed, that there is no transaction on etherscan from smart contract to my account.

In short: i try to send money to contract and receive back a half of sent amount. Here is a code of fallback function (really simple):

```
function () payable {
    uint money = msg.value;
    uint half = money / 2;
    msg.sender.transfer(half);
}
```

For example, when i send 6 eth on contract, i receive back 3. It works, and i see transaction of sending 6 eth to contract in etherscan. But i don't see transaction of sending 3 eth back to my address.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

There's no second transaction. Sending the 6 ether and getting 3 ether back are part of the same transaction. If you link to the transaction on Etherscan, I can help more, but generally look for the "Internal Transactions" tab when viewing the transaction to see what sorts of things happened during the transaction.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, i wanted to see internal transactions, but there is no "internal transactions" tab. Here is a link to transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4b2c8d004db8c8089b51cde68da72c4f8cdf787360c93889935959807802a776

Comment: Sorry, perhaps only calls to other smart contracts show up in "internal transactions"?